# Should I use Observable(RxJava2) or Call (retrofit2)?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

TL;DR: I want to execute multiple `Call`s (Retrofit) like you can `.zip()` multiple `Observable`s (RxJava2).

---

I have a retrofit2 function:

```
@GET("/data/price")
Call<JsonObject> getBookTitle(@Query("id") String id, @Query("lang") String lang);
```

I can execute it (async) in code with `enquene()`:

```
ApiProvider.getBooksAPI().getBookTitle(bookId, "en").enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) { }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) { }
});
```

Now I want to execute multiple `Call`s at once (get multiple book titles) and be notified when all requests are done. Here is when I am missing knowledge.

I know I could start using `Observable` (RXJava2) instead of `Call` (Retrofit2):

```
@GET("/data/price")
Observable<JsonObject> getBookTitle(@Query("id") String id, @Query("lang") String lang);
```

and then merge calls like in below example. But this code seems much more complex and long (especially if I only need 1 book title). Isn't there any way I could merge `Call`s without using `Observable`?

```
List<Observable<JsonObject>> mergedCalls = new ArrayList<>();
mergedCalls.add(ApiProvider.getBooksAPI().getBookTitle(bookId1, "en"));
mergedCalls.add(ApiProvider.getBooksAPI().getBookTitle(bookId2, "en"));
mergedCalls.add(ApiProvider.getBooksAPI().getBookTitle(bookId3, "en"));

Observable<List<JsonObject>> observable = Observable.zip(calls, responses -> { 
        // merge responses, return List
        ...
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

observer = new DisposableObserver<List<JsonObject>> () {
    @Override
    public void onNext(List<JsonObject> result) { // got all API results }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) { }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() { }
};

observable.subscribe(observer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RxJava` **is the** easy way of merging Retrofit `Calls`. Merging `Calls` manually by `enqueuing` all `Calls` and doing something when all of them invoke `onResponse`, will probably be more complex than simply using `Observable.zip(...)`.

The other choice that you have is using Kotlin coroutines (now Retrofit has out of the box support for them). But that depends on the Kotlin presence in your code and your willingness of using coroutines.

---

**EDIT:**
*(Answering your question from the comment)*

If you really think about `Calls` and `RxJava` `Observables` you don't really have to do anything *more* when using `RxJava`. When using raw `Calls` you still have to:

1. Make sure you're on the right thread if you want to touch `Views` (`observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`)
2. Make sure you're touching network on the right thread (`subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`)
3. Make sure you're not using the response when your `Activity`/`Fragment`/`Something else` is no longer present (disposing of the `Disposable` in `RxJava` handles that)

---

You can significantly simplify your example:

1. Don't create `Observable` & `Observer`. Simply use the `subscribe` method which returns `Disposable`. And then maintain just this one `Disposable`.
2. You probably don't need `onComplete` so you can use the simpler version of `.subscribe(...)`
3. You can remove the need for `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` by properly creating your `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())` when building the `Retrofit` instance.

```
BooksApi booksApi = ApiProvider.getBooksAPI();
List<Observable<JsonObject>> mergedCalls = new ArrayList<>();
mergedCalls.add(booksApi.getBookTitle(bookId1, "en"));
mergedCalls.add(booksApi.getBookTitle(bookId2, "en"));
mergedCalls.add(booksApi.getBookTitle(bookId3, "en"));

final Disposable disposable = Observable
        .zip(mergedCalls, responses -> {
            // merge responses, return List
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(list -> {
            // got all API results
        }, throwable -> {

        });
```

Doing that for one call would be as simple as:

```
final Disposable disposable = booksApi
        .getBookTitle(bookId1, "en")
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(title -> {
            // got the result
        }, throwable -> {

        });
```

Comment: Sadly I don't use Kotlin in this project. Let's say I start using `Observable`. Is there any shorther way (compared to my last code above) to get just 1 book title? With `Call` there are no extra objects, but with `Observable` I need to make `Observable`, `Observer` and take care to properly dispose everything etc, which makes code very ugly as opposed to `Call`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is much clearer now! Last thing - can I simply dispose disposable in end of `.subscribe()`? I want this to execute only once and then I'm done.

Comment: when you `dispose()` a `Disposable` it means that you're no longer interested in anything the `observable` might produce (results or errors). So `disposing` a `Disposable` before you receive the result will mean you won't receive it (the answer to your question is "no"). Typically you would `dispose` it in the `onDestroy`-kind of a callback of an Activity or a Fragment...

Comment: You want to execute it only once but you can't be sure how long it will take. It might take a fraction of a second, or a few seconds (depending on the timeout values). So you can only depend on disposing it when it no longer makes sense to display it to the user (e.g. user closes a related screen).

Comment: I agree with everything, but I still don't understand why I cant dispose it inside (as last line) of `.subscribe` lambda. The body of lambda will be executed when we get results. Please see https://pastebin.com/raw/Zr0xD38x.

Comment: 1. I thought you meant `.subscribe(...).dispose()`
2. The problem with your suggested approach is that you cannot be sure `onNext` (so the first `Consumer` from `subscribe` method) is called while you still have your UI element visible. If the related UI element is closed, and some time after that you receive your `onNext`, it might be subject to a memory leak. This depends on your whole setup. Hard to judge from those snippets.

Comment: Agree about memory leak problem. I will inspect the code deeply and with your tips I'm sure I will handle this.